# При воспроизведения скрипта с помощью 'Crontab' путь не тот который нужен

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

Есть простой скрипт который записывает данные:

```
with open('http.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write(px)
```

Сам путь до скрипта:

```
/home/bot/proxy/proxy_update.py
```

Если выполнять скрипт с помощью обычной bash команды:

`python3.6 /home/bot/proxy/proxy_updater.py`

То всё отлично срабатывает, и файл `http.txt` создаётся именно в корневой папке выполняемого скрипта `/home/bot/proxy_update/http.txt`

Но когда скрипт пытается выполнить планировщик задач `Crontab` то файл http.txt создаётся в корневой папке `/root`

Как можно это исправить что бы файл создавался в той же директории где и находится сам скрипт?

Сама задача в `Crontab`:

```
0 0 * * * python3.6 /home/bot/proxy/proxy_update.py
```

Comment: создайте задание для вашего пользователя, а не для пользователя root. для этого запустите `$ crontab -e` от имени этого пользователя, а не от имени пользователя root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` - получить путь к той папке, где лежит скрипт.

`os.path.join(path, name)` - создать полный путь до файла.

В целом примерно так:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd() # Current Working Directory
name = "text.txt"
fullname = os.path.join(cwd, name)
with open(fullname, 'w') as f:
    # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо указать абсолютный путь до файла. Что бы скрипт обращался к файлу из нужной папки.